# Pass context from one serializer to another?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

With Django REST Framework, I have 2 serializers: `PageSerializer` and `CommentSerializer`.

`CommentSerializer` depends on some extra "context" value, but it doesn't get it directly, instead it needs to get it from `PageSerializer`, since they have a nested relationship.

So I need to have something like this:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_my_field(self, comment):
        my_value = self.context['my_value']
        ...

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    comments = CommentSerializer(
        many=True,
        context={'my_value': my_value} # my_value doesn't exist until __init__ is called, so I can't pass it
    )

...
my_value = 1
page_serializer = PageSerializer(page, context={'my_value': my_value})
```

But, of course, this code can't work.
What kind of workaround can I do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the relationship in the serializer like you did, `PageSerializer`'s context will be automatically passed to `CommentSerializer` when the page's comments are serialized.

So, just defining `comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)` will do.